# Apache2 collecting unique visitors, How?

Tags: apache2

I have a cloud server running apache2 for hosting my website, while attempting to monetise it, I keep getting asked to supply proof of unique visits per month. I know I could add code to log all this to my DB, how ever this seems like a bit of an inefficient way of doing things.

I'm sure apache2 must log visits, so my question is, how do i monitor the unique visits with apache2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics is the trusted industry standard when advertisers/investors ask for proof of uniques. They may not trust any internal tools as you could edit data before exporting them.